# Shuffle Image Function

Tags: jquery

I am tryin to shuffle images around in a table , I have this piece of code which worked when the images were not in a table, I want it to work when they are in the table -

```
    var a = $("#deck > div").remove().toArray();
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var bi = a[i];
    var bj = a[j];
    a[i] = bj;
    a[j] = bi;
}
$("#deck").append(a);
```

and this is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/39/

any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The classic randomization example in JavaScript is to do a random sort:

```
myArray.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
```

Basically, the array sort function lets you evaluate two elements and choose the order by returning a positive or negative value.  Sorting with a random function will randomly provide the positive or negative value, causing the array to be randomly sorted.  In your code, it would be:

```
var array = $("#deck > div").remove().toArray();
array.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
$("#deck").append(array);
```